# Why does this Minecraft Rotation Command not work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm recreating the Donkey Kong arcade game in Minecraft, and I want Kong to be facing a certain way the whole time, so I put this command in a repeating command block:

`/execute as @e[name="Donkey Kong"] run data modify entity @s {Rotation: [180d, 0d]}`

It does nothing; it doesn't even spit out an error message.

Comment: Welcome to arqade.se! Take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need of guidance.

Comment: Modifying nbt data of entities is finicky due to the functionality of how that works. You're essentially replacing that entity with a new one instead of simply updating those fields. I imagine that might be part of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why your command didn't work. I tried:

```
/execute as @e[name="Donkey Kong"] run data modify entity @s {Rotation: [180f, 0f]}
```

...but that didn't work either.

I know of a workaround using the `/tp` command:

```
/execute as @e[name="Donkey Kong"] at @s run tp @s ~ ~ ~ 180 0
```

Comment: The command doesn't work because they were attempting to merge but used `/data modify`.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing this:

```
/execute as @e[name="Donkey Kong"] at @s run data merge entity @s {Rotation:[180.0f,0.0f]}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the command you provided answers the question rather than merely tossing readers a fish.